# How to block access to specific URL in grails

Tags: url, grails, spring-security

I have urls like 
http://192.168.0.226:8080/crm/contacts/contactProfile/5

A company can create an account and then create contacts. It generates contact id that is used in the URL. And any company can access contacts of another company just by replacing the id by a random number like

http://192.168.0.226:8080/crm/contacts/contactProfile/675

How do i prevent one company to access contacts of another company. And also if the id is not in database it will show error. How can i redirect to 404 page if id is not there.

I am using grails 2.2.1 with spring security. I tried to solve it by requestmap as

```
    def structureMap2 = Requestmap.findByUrl("contacts/contactProfile/*") ?: new Requestmap(url: "contacts/contactProfile/*",configAttribute: "ROLE_COMPANY").save(failOnError:true)
```

but it didn't worked.

If i have to restructure URL, how do i do that. Or there is another other way to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd do it in `Contacts/contactProfile` controller method.
Check, if the user accessing it has the right to open it. If Yes, You render the page, if not, give back the flash.error (or any other) and redirect to the 404. Something like this:

```
def contactProfile() {
    def user = = springSecurityService.currentUser
    def contact = Contact.get(params.id)
    if (!contact) {
        flash.error = "There is no such contact!"
        redirect(controller: "errors", action: "404")
    } else if (contact.company.id == user.company.id) {
        //create the stuff
        [contact: contact] //render the page
    } else {
        flash.error = "You are not authorised to view this contact!"
        redirect(controller: "errors", action: "404")
    }
}
```

This is written assuming that You have company assigned to the user and the contact also has a company it is created for.